# Rserve() error in the first instance of running a Java application

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am writing a `Java` application in IntelliJ IDE. The application uses `Rserve()` to connect to `R` and access scripts. I have a java script which sends a command to the shell to start `Rserve()`. The problem I am facing now is the first time when I run the application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.rosuda.REngine.REngineException.<init>(Lorg/rosuda/REngine/REngine;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException.<init>(RserveException.java:59)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:90)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:60)
    at org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection.<init>(RConnection.java:44)
    at de.uni_jena.bioinformatik.RecalibrationGUI.Application.main(Application.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

And, when the next time I run the application, it works perfectly. From what I can understand, in the first run, it just established the `Rserve()` connection and then in the second run it works. Can someone help me fix this, so that the application connects to `Rserve()` in the first instance and also runs perfectly?

Here is the java class which calls `Rserve()`

```
public class InvokeRserve {
    public static boolean invoke() {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("R CMD Rserve --vanilla");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Rserve connection: Exception occurred: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And, here is the main java class which starts the application and calls the `invoke()` method:

```
public class Application {
    /**
     * Main method for the Swing application
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            boolean value = InvokeRserve.invoke();
        RConnection check = new RConnection();
        if(check.isConnected())
        {
            // Run the GUI construction in the Event-Dispatching thread for thread-safety
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                /**
                 * run method which create a new GUIMain object
                 */
                @Override
                public void run() {new GUIMain("Java Application"); // Let the constructor do the job
                }
            });
       }
        else
        System.out.println("There was no R connection found.");
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to stop an existing `Rserve()` connection (I read different answers which suggest using `shutdown()`, but it is not working for me)? Every time, I have to restart my computer to shutdown an existing connection and start a new connection to test the above code.

I also looked into the `StartRserve.java` example file at http://www.rforge.net/DATRAS/files/org/rosuda/Mondrian/StartRserve.java. But when I use the method `StartRserve.checkLocalRserve()` in the main class of my application, I get the same `Rserve()` error as shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `invoke()` method returns before Rserve is actually started, so you're apparently trying to connect too early. You may want to add `p.waitFor();`. See also the `StartRserve` class which is far more robust in starting Rserve from Java.

PS: I'd recommend using the [stats-rosuda-devel mailing list](https://mailman.rz.uni-augsburg.de/mailman/listinfo/stats-rosuda-devel) for Rserve questions which gives you much faster responses.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for shutting Rserve connection withoutt shutting down the computer. Try this while opening an Rconnection:

```
    RConnection rconn=null;
    try{
        rconn=new RConnection();
        //Your personal code here

    } catch(Exception exc){
        exc.printStackTrace(out);
    } finally{
        if (rconn!=null){
            rconn.close();
        }
    }
```

This way when the app stops halfway with an exception, it still runs the finally part and closes the connection.
Hope this helps in time.

As for the exception-part details, it would be possible to answer if you could display the line numbers beside the code, as the exception log refers to the code by line numbers.